# Joining objects in Blender 2.8 causes the objects to disapear

Tags: objects

I created multiple objects in Blender 2.8 using the Bezier curves and converted them to Mesh using the Object->Convert To->Mesh from Curve.

[image]

Now for whatever reason when I select all of the objects in object mode and do "Ctrl+J" to join them, 5 of the objects disappear and I'm left with only one.

[image]

I tried to replicate this again, but it's working fine for all of the other objects I try to join, it only acts like this for these 6 specific objects. I tried to select them and export them and then re-import, but for some reason blender is exporting only 80bytes for the STL, not sure if it's related or not.

When I go into the edit mode, I can see that they're all "Mesh" instead of "Curve" why is it acting like this? I never have faced this issue before, maybe I enabled some kind of 'property' for the object that causes this? Thanks!

Here is the Blend file:
[image]

Comment: Sound confusing, can you upload the file with those 6 objects to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com?

Comment: @Leander I uploaded and updated my post, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug. But you can use a helper object, to merge these objects.

1. Add a Curve Object. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Curve* > *Bezier*
2. Go into edit mode <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> and delete <kbd>X</kbd> the selected control points leaving you with an empty bezier. Exit edit mode <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>.
3. Select all other objects with the border selection <kbd>B</kbd>. [Make sure, that the newly created (empty) bezier object stays the active object.]
4. Merge them with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and Leander's solution did not work for me. It seems to have occurred because I mirrored an object using negative scaling factor (probably).

The two objects I was joining had different transforms, so the joining process had to resolve that. Applying the transforms manually also caused the object to "disappear".

My solution was to:

1. apply transforms (object disappears! maybe bug as suggested by Leander?)
2. recalculate normals (object reappears!)
3. join with no issues.

I'm using version 2.90.1

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well... this (weirdly) worked for me:

1. Highlight all items you wish to joint
2. Right click > Convert to Mesh
3. Right click > Join

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The cause seemed to be that object had no depth at one side. It worked after using the *Solidify* modifier.